# Loading next set of articles in array

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am loading up articles from JSON data into an array. When you click on a specific post, it loads the corresponding article based on the postID/position in the array and then loads a slider.

I would like to post the next few articles in the array into the next few slides in the slider. I have attempted to do this and attached snippets of what I have done.

Please let me know if you need anything more -

Code -

```js
    var slideCount = 1;

    $('.swiper-slide:nth-child(1)').html(articleArray[(pageNumber - 1)][postID].content);

    $.each(articleArray[0], function(i) {
        slideCount++;
         //FOR some reason, this if statement skips slides. If you click on the first article, it will on append to slide 3 onwards, if you click on article two, it only appends to article 4 onwards
        if(i > postID){
            articleContent = articleArray[(pageNumber - 1)][i].content;
        }
        console.log(slideCount);
        $('.swiper-slide:nth-child(' + slideCount + ')').html(articleContent);
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You say you've attempted to do it, so it would help if you would explain the problem you're having with your attempt.

Comment: please add any extra code and information to the question itself by editing it, code in comments is very difficult to read and understand due to the lack of formatting. Thanks.

Comment: I will do so, thanks.